# bash solution to dynamically build value for prefix parameter of my tagging script for AWS CLI commands

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I am calling AWS CLI commands in a bash script. I have a need to add tags to files whose prefix is as follows:

```
/base/user1/foo/file1
/base/user2/foo/fileA
/base/user3/foo/fileX
```

I only want to delete those under "foo", but if user has files like:

```
/base/user1/bar/fileZ
```

, I don't want to delete those under "bar".

I have a script:

!/bin/bash

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key}' --prefix myPrefix --output text  | xargs -n 1 aws s3api put-object-tagging  --bucket myBucket --tagging "{\"TagSet\": [{ \"Key\": \"myKey\", \"Value\": \"myValue\" }]}" --key
```

This works fine as long as myPrefix is an absolute path like:

```
/base/user1/foo/
```

, but I have too many users to manual do this, so I wanted to do something like:

```
/base/*/foo/
```

for the prefix. However, that throws an error:

An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the PutObjectTagging operation: The specified key does not exist

Is there a way in bash in a loop or something that traverses down to the "foo" level so that I can have the full path: prefix /base/user1/foo/, /base/user2/foo, /ase/user3/foo  dynamically defined for the prefix? Thanks for any response.

Comment: `find / -type d -name foo -print` will list all foo directories under / and print the full path to each.  You can then use `grep` to filter the ones you want (or do not want with `-v`).  Once you have the list you expect, you can add a `while` loop (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and process each of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a decent solution on my own. Replacing this line from the original post:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key}' --prefix myPrefix --output text  | xargs -n 1 aws s3api put-object-tagging  --bucket myBucket --tagging "{\"TagSet\": [{ \"Key\": \"myKey\", \"Value\": \"myValue\" }]}" --key
```

, with the following:

```
for BUCKET_PATH in $(aws s3 ls --recursive --summarize $BUCKET);
do
if [[ $BUCKET_PATH == *$PREFIX* ]]; then
  echo $BUCKET_PATH
  aws s3api put-object-tagging  --bucket ${BUCKET} --key ${BUCKET_PATH} --tagging "{\"TagSet\": [{ \"Key\": \"${KEY}\", \"Value\": \"${VALUE}\" }]}"
fi
done
```

works great.

Comment: I'm trying to echo before I run a very similar action and there's something about the [{ }] that causes bash to disorder the sequence of characters.  idk if it's just echo, but when I tested this earlier, s3api was not happy.  Even escaping seems to do very little.

Will post an alternate solution as well if I can get it working :(